# MSSQL Stored Procedure help comparing Dates

Tags: sql-server

I've never written a stored procedure before. I am using SSMS 2014 and I am trying insert records based on a date comparison.

So essentially. I want to grab the **MAX** date that i have in table **B**. I want to store that somewhere and then only insert records from table **A** who's date is > than table B's max date. Am I using the wrong approach? I am getting the error: *An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.*

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 A
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 B
    ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.LastDate, 101) > CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(B.LastDate), 101)

END
```

Comment: Two major issues. First, you should never convert dates to strings for comparisons. Second, if you use varchar you should ALWAYS specify a size. For the issue at hand it seems that a subquery or cte may be better suited to the task at hand.

Comment: I always converting the varchar to a date, not a date to string.

Comment: No, you are converting your LastDate column to a varchar (which is a string).

Comment: You are correct. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it as below:

If you need to insert the data then you can directly insert using `Select ... Insert`

```
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME;

SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(B.LastDate) FROM dbo.Table2 B

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 A
WHERE A.LastDate > @MaxDate
```

Comment: Ahh, I just had to get rid of the B after the Insert, it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much guessing here as there isn't a lot of detail but perhaps something more like this is what you are looking for? More than likely you need to correlate the subquery but not really sure what you requirements are.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Table1 A
where A.LastDate >
(
    select max(B.LastDate)
    from dbo.Table2 B
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want columns from `TableA` as noted by *only insert records from table A who's date is > than table B's max date*, you can use a derived table in the join.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM dbo.Table1 A
INNER JOIN (select max(LastDate) DT from  dbo.Table2) b
ON A.LastDate > b.DT
```

Or in a `WHERE` clause which would be quicker.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM dbo.Table1 A
WHERE A.LastDate > (select max(LastDate) DT from dbo.Table2)
```